# XenServer 6.2 guest network configuration

Tags: virtualization, xenserver, citrix, guest

None of VMs I tried to install can't reach internet. I have Xensever 6.2 installed on a server with single NIC, which can be accessed via 2 public IPs. XenServer can ping google.com and seems to be configured correctly.

Here's ifconfig output

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:1031298 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:1204189 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:446121200 (425.4 MiB) TX bytes:799451138 (762.4 MiB)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1 RX packets:462703 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:462703 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:1266255929 (1.1 GiB) TX bytes:1266255929 (1.1 GiB)

vif41.0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP PROMISC MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:32 RX bytes:76 (76.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vif41.1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP PROMISC MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:32 RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:134 (134.0 B)

xapi2 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr FE:F8:68:1E:C6:44 UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:90 (90.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

xenbr0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx inet addr:xxx.xxx.xx.xx Bcast:xxx.xxx.xx.xx Mask:255.255.255.224 UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:1023828 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:821767 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:449123469 (428.3 MiB) TX bytes:775128231 (739.2 MiB)

xenbr0:0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy inet addr:yy.yy.yy.yyy Bcast:yy.yy.yy.yy Mask:yy.yyy.yyy.yyy UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1`

brctl show output

bridge name bridge id STP enabled interfaces xenbr0 0000.002590d9a98e no vif43.0 eth0 xe pif-list uuid ( RO) : e790d4ba-c838-fc22-721f-7a98854029f7 device ( RO): eth0 currently-attached ( RO): true VLAN ( RO): -1 network-uuid ( RO): a4105d8f-e7ba-c5e2-1007-db34fe5cf6f7
```

I installed vm with network attached to it and it can't access internet. Do I need to configure the guest vm the special way, and if so how it can be done.

Comment: Can't open the imgur picture. I'll just ask you some questions: 1. Have you tried pinging the default gateway from the VM? 2. Have you tried doing a traceroute to, let's say, 8.8.8.8?

Comment: When I try to ping 8.8.8.8(which is set as DNS) says that Destination host unreachable from inet addr of xenbr0

Comment: Please tell me: What are the IP addresses of the XenServer host (as written on `xsconsole`), and what are the IP addresses of the VM (as you planned).

Comment: You can't use the same IP as the host. XenServer must have its own IP, and each VM within XenServer must each have their own IP.

Comment: I did't plan to. I actually find the problem already. Thank you for participating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Hetzner dropped any packets coming from my randomly assigned mac addresses. So it did't work unless I assigned real macs to my VM.